# How to add static typing to React Function Component with Flow Type using Declaration File?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have a simple React Component which I already added inline Flow type:

`src/MyComponent.jsx`

```
// @flow
type MyComponentProps = {
  id: number,
  name: string
}

const MyComponent = ({ id, name}: MyComponentProps) =>
  <div>{`My name is ${name} and ${id} is my ID.`}</div>

export (MyComponent: MyComponentProps => React$Node)
```

The problem is the component gets a little dirty with the inline annotations and when you implement the component, the IDE tooltip is not really clear about what properties it can take:

[image: MyComponent props are not clear]

The best I could do was changing the export of `MyComponent` specifying the props one by one. This makes the IDE Tooltip clearer:

`export default (MyComponent: ({ name: string, id: number }) => React$Node)`
[image]

But the code gets even messier.

I saw that you can create a [Declaration File](https://flow.org/en/docs/declarations/) and move the typing there, but I just can't make it work and couldn't find an example for React Function Component.

This is what I have, but this doesn't work.

`src/MyComponent.jsx.flow`

```
// @flow
declare module 'MyComponent' {
  declare type MyComponentProps = {
    id: number,
    name: string
  }
  declare export function MyComponent(props: MyComponentProps): React$Node}
```

Can you help me to move the type to the external file definition, please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you shouldn't be trying to move your definitions to another file. Writing them inline has the advantage of making the actual component type checked with the props it accepts as opposed to only for the components using this `MyComponent`.

Have you tried this? Which moves the annotation position to where the component is defined. Which means if you ever add JSDocs they will also appear correctly in your IDE.

```
// @flow
type MyComponentProps = {
  id: number,
  name: string
}

/**
 * It allows you to comment like this
 */
const MyComponent = ({ id, name}: MyComponentProps): React$Node =>
  <div>{`My name is ${name} and ${id} is my ID.`}</div>

export MyComponent
```

I'd also say that code being messy or clean is quite subjective, though I feel the same way about annotation on the export looks "messy". So the above example is how I generally write my components.